# Powershell Xml file >> Creating a folder

Tags: xml, powershell, directory

I want to create a folder with the name of the `xml` file in PowerShell from a part of an `xml` file.

I found something like that, but instead of a folder it's a txt file:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\config.xml)
$xml.config.compare.source
$xml.config.compare.parameters.parameter[0]
$xml.config.compare.source >> c:\temp\output.txt
```

Can not I use that to create a folder?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What name do you expect?

Comment: <!--
<config>
  <compare>
    <source>c:\...\</source>
    <Name="Test562">
    <parameters> 

I want to create the name in xml as a folder

Comment: You mean Test562? Are you able to get that value?

Comment: Yes exactly. With the txt file it works but I do not know how to make a folder out of it

Answer (score 1):

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<config>
    <compare>
        <original name="Test123" />
    </compare>
</config>
"@

# Get value from the XML
Write-Host $xml.config.compare.original.name

$newDirectory = Join-Path -Path "C:\Users" -ChildPath $env:USERNAME
Write-Host $newDirectory
$newDirectory = Join-Path -Path $newDirectory -ChildPath $xml.config.compare.original.name
Write-Host $newDirectory

# Create a folder using one of the values
New-Item -Path $newDirectory -ItemType Directory
```

Comment: It does not work. I'll try another example:
I have an xml file on my desktop "Test.xml"
<html lang="en">
 <config>
  <Original Name="Test123">

And I want under C: \ Users \ $ env: UserName \ Desktop \ Test \ a folder with the name of the xml file "Original Name". Just without naming the name "Test123".

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can I name the order even further? New-Item -Path $ newDirectory + TEXT -ItemType Directory ... Then there is a + between the names

Comment: Is it also possible to get the same in a .ini?

Comment: @timsen96 yes. I would recommend raising another question to answer that problem though. Please include the `*.ini` file contents and as much detail as you can (this question was too light on information).

Answer (score 0):

Shorter answer

```
$NewDir = Join-Path -Path "C:\Users" -ChildPath $env:USERNAME | 

New-Item -Path $NewDir -Name $xml.config.compare.original.name -ItemType Directory
```

Alternatively Since the variable for C:\Users\CurrentUser alreay exists as $HOME :

```
New-Item -Path $NewDir -Name $xml.config.compare.original.name -ItemType Directory
```